# Is it possible to place a railway that goes east to west in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Whenever I place a rail in 1.13.2, it is oriented north-south, is possible to place an east-west rail in minecraft?  How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless for some reason you need a single track. Place a second track to the east or west of the first one it should reorient east-west.
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Rail

Comment: …and if you need a single piece, just place a second and break it again.

Answer (score 4):

As of 1.15, rails now place in the direction you are looking.

Answer (score 0):

in 1.14 and any earlier versions, it would Always place North-South, if you wanna redirect it, place Another rail to the East / West of it, then remove the additional track so you'll be left with a single track again, and this time the single track would be Facing east-west

however in 1.15 and any newer versions, the rail would Always face the way you're lookin when you place it.